# Generate random string for dynamic input in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have input fields inside `v-for` loop:

```
<div v-show="id" v-for="(entry, index) in model.$.tokens" :key="'current' + index">
   <input type="text" v-model="entry.title">
   <input type="text" v-model="entry.token">
   <button type="button" @click="generate(entry.token)">Generate random token</button>
</div>
```

And I want to generate random string for `v-model="entry.token` after clicking Generate random token button:

```
generate(value) {
  value = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
  return value;
}
```

I tried this but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make much sense returning things on event handlers. It would be better in my opinion to pass the whole object and modify it, as follow:

```html
<div v-show="id" v-for="(entry, index) in model.$.tokens" :key="'current' + index">
   <input type="text" v-model="entry.title">
   <input type="text" v-model="entry.token">
   <button type="button" @click="generate(entry)">Generate random token</button>
</div>
```

```js
generate(entry) {
  entry.token = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing and returning *value*

```
generate(payload) {
  token = String(payload) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
  return token;
}
```